# Ubuntu 20.04 PCIe Bus error severity=corrected

Tags: 20.04, pcie

I have a problem with new ubuntu, after suspend i always crash and i need to reboot system

my kernel parameters "quiet splash pci=noaer pci=noamsi"

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsWLR.png)

Comment: `pci=noamsi` should be `pci=nomsi`. Temporarily remove BOTH `pci=` and reboot, so we can get a genuine error list. Edit your question and show me the entire text of the errors, not a screenshot, please. Also show me `lspci -tv` and `lspci -nn`.

Comment: Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer. And `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xZvTRJcS

Comment: Can u tell me how i can copy error message?

Comment: i see in the logs that the device from error is nvmc

Comment: To copy an error message from the `terminal` screen, just select the desired text, then right-click, and select COPY. Edit your question and PASTE the clipboard.

Comment: To determine if your BIOS is current, I need the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: Please see my partial answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete answer... edits forthcoming...

**nomsi**

In your GRUB edits, `pci=noamsi` should be `pci=nomsi`... but we'll temporarily remove both `pci=` statements for now.

**BIOS**

You have BIOS version F.53.

To determine if there's a newer BIOS, I need the exact make/model # of your computer.

---

**vm.swappiness**

With only 8G RAM and 4G swap, vm.swappiness=10 is totally wrong.

Set vm.swappiness=60 (based on 8G RAM and 4G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`

---

**AER errors**

AER errors are `Advanced Error Reporting` correctable errors on the PCIe bus.

From the initial information available, it appears that it might be this device:

```
Lite-On Technology Corporation Device 23f1
```

Do you recognize this device? Is it your NVMe SSD? Is this a laptop or desktop computer?

We **MAY** end up putting `pci=noaer` in your GRUB to circumvent these errors, but more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error log to the [picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsWLR.png), with type switching between `Data Link Layer` and `Physical Layer` appearing ~10000x per second in my `/var/log/syslog`:

```
... kernel: [706130.943401] pcieport 0000:00:06.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:03:00.0
... kernel: [706130.943403] nvme 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
... kernel: [706130.943404] nvme 0000:03:00.0:   device [1cc1:5350] error status/mask=00000040/0000e000
... kernel: [706130.943404] nvme 0000:03:00.0:    [ 6] BadTLP
```

For me, based on [this Arch post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232917), I edited GRUB with `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, specifically updating it to include `pci=noaer`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
```

After a reboot, that at least silenced AER for me, with the noted caveat that:

> "... although that also disables reporting of non-correctable AER errors".

Comment: That stated, today the 1TB XPG Gammix S50 Lite Gen4 NVMe device is [RMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization), so most likely the above was an early indication of upcoming hardware failure.